# Onclick add value to textfield?

Tags: html, onclick, keyboard, textfield

I'm trying to code an onscreen keyboard but can't see why the keys when clicked do not insert the values, instead nothing happens. Sorry if this is a obvious problem, I am trying to learn.

```
        <tr>
                <td colspan="3"> <B>Search</B>
                    <div id="keyboard">
```

```
<br>
<input id="searchbox" type="text">
<br>
    <input id="qkey" type="button" value="q" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='q';"/>
    <input id="wkey" type="button" value="w" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='w';"/>
    <input id="ekey" type="button" value="e" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='e';"/>
    <input id="rkey" type="button" value="r" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='r';"/>
    <input id="tkey" type="button" value="t" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='t';"/>
    <input id="ykey" type="button" value="y" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='y';"/>
    <input id="ukey" type="button" value="u" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='u';"/>
    <input id="ikey" type="button" value="i" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='i';"/>
    <input id="okey" type="button" value="o" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='o';"/>
    <input id="pkey" type="button" value="p" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='p';"/>
    <input id="backkey" type="button" value="Bckspc" onclick='bckspc'>
    <br>
    <input id="akey" type="button" value="a" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='a';"/>
    <input id="skey" type="button" value="s" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='s';"/>
    <input id="dkey" type="button" value="d" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='d';"/>
    <input id="fkey" type="button" value="f" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='f';"/>
    <input id="gkey" type="button" value="g" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='g';"/>
    <input id="hkey" type="button" value="h" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='h';"/>
    <input id="jkey" type="button" value="j" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='j';"/>
    <input id="kkey" type="button" value="k" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='k';"/>
    <input id="lkey" type="button" value="l" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='l';"/>
    <br>
    <input id="zkey" type="button" value="z" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='z';"/>
    <input id="xkey" type="button" value="x" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='x';"/>
    <input id="ckey" type="button" value="c" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='c';"/>
    <input id="vkey" type="button" value="v" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='v';"/>
    <input id="bkey" type="button" value="b" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='b';"/>
    <input id="nkey" type="button" value="n" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='n';"/>
    <input id="mkey" type="button" value="m" onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+='m';"/>
    <br>
    <input id="spacekey" type="button" value="                  space                  " onClick="document.getElementById("searchbox").value+=' ';"/>
            </center>
            </div>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used the wrong quotation marks in the onclick.  Instead, use

```
<input id="qkey" type="button" value="q" onClick="document.getElementById('searchbox').value+='q';"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use simple quotes, i.e. `'searchbox'` in place of `"searchbox"`. You are specifying a quoted text in another quoted text, thus you need either to use different quotes or use escaping (like `\"`)